# Will Ansible work in case of Windows Jump Server?

Tags: windows, ansible

I wanted to know if we have Windows jump server instead or bastion server will Ansible work? if yes how can we achieve this

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, via [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html).

Send the WinRM traffic to Nginx. Configure Nginx in a way that each target host has an their own url.

- example.com/tn1
- example.com/tn2

Let each node point to your [my.fqdn.com](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/domains/domain-administration/fqdn-fully-qualified-domain-name/)/wsman.

Look at this [pull request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/12054).

Comment: sure @Kevin C will give a try